# Fetch data from a different website using PHP

Tags: php

Ok guys, I'm starting to be really good at using PHP, but I really want to learn more and expand my knowledge. Just today, I was thinking about fetching data from other websites and using their content to display some of their content into any site that I will build later on. I have been looking on the Net, and I came across several sites that are pretty much interesting, but with different solutions. My question are:

1. What is the proper way to fetch data from other websites?
2. Should I look into Web Services? Is that a way to fetch data from other sites?

Thank you!

Comment: "web services" is a pretty broad topic in itself, and it means different things to different people-- however, if the site you want to syndicate info from provides data via web services (eg. a REST API or something) then by all means use that.

Comment: Try this `echo file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');` to see how easy this can be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

exact term you looking for is **cross-domain requests**

[`CURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) is best for PHP.

[other tutorials](http://www.geoffmartin.co.uk/blog/2-blog/5-cross-domain-form-post-using-php)

have a look below too

- The new [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (CORS) standard, if the browsers your users use support it and the server has support for it. Note that a lot of general web users still have browsers that don't support it.
- [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP) ("JSON with padding"), which is basically a dynamically-added `script` element
- Using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) (Yahoo Query Language) as a [cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax)

Comment: as long as you stay on the PHP side (server side vs the JavaScript one aka client side), you don't have to think about cross-domain restrictions.

Comment: I always prefer server side over client side. lol

Answer (score 5):

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

or [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Comment: Thank you, I have heard of curl, but I have never used it. How about Web Services?

Answer (score 1):

Depends for what reasons you want to contact the other site.
If you want their database... you could connect using their URL and username/password.
If you want to display their site, or a part, use a frame.

if you are a lazy bum and want to use part of their site to use for your own...
Download the page, or just include it(hard to get working properly :P)

Comment: HAHAHAHAH...I will look into the first two options!